# Android How can i override exported tag in manifest?

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

I want to upgrade target sdk from 30 to 31. But i'm getting that error :

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly
> specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are
> required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the
> corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See
> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported
> for details.

When i'm look around in manifest merger. I see one of the third party library which i use in the app didn't add `android:exported` tag.

```
 <service android:name="com.****.MessagingService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

So here is my question. How can i override this service as exported false like below ?

```
<service android:exported="false"
 android:name="com.****.MessagingService" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Studio will merge all manifest files of your project and its dependencies.

The upper level manifests can always take priority and overwrite the values in the dependencies. Check this [paragraph in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#merge_conflict_heuristics).

Since the dependencies do not specify the `exported` value at all, you can overwrite each service in your top level manifest file like this:

```
<service android:exported="false"
 android:name="com.****.MessagingService" />
```

This will merge the values for the service tag for `com.****.MessagingService` and apply the exported value.

Answer (score 1):

You can either replace the whole node

```
        <service
            tools:node="replace"
            android:name=".MessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Or just the attribute you need to replace

```
        <service
            tools:replace="exported"
            android:name=".MessagingService"
            android:exported="false"/>
```

You can find more information about this topic [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests)