# I get android:exported error even though I set all

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-12

The error is this.

```
Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
```

the AndroidManifest.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.kakao.talk" />
    </queries>

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="${appLabel}"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.allow_multiple_resumed_activities"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.kakao.sdk.AppKey"
            android:value="@string/kakao_native_app_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".components.ui.entry.EntryActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I don't understand why this error occurs.

Comment: All of your implemented libraries also need to be specified `android:exported`. Did you check that?

Comment: yes, I solved this issue. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because some libraries that I used was not handled well with 31. So, some libraries didn't specify `exported` attribute in their AndriodManifest.xml

In my case, the libraries were not used so, I just deleted them in the project and I solved that issue.

To check libraries manifests.xml, First of all, you need to go to AndroidManifest.xml and then at the bottom, there are two tabs - `text` and `Merged Manifest`.

text is for the current project. And `Merged Manifest` is the entire manifest after all libraries come together.

So, you can check whether some of your libraries missed `exported` attribute in their manifest file.

After finding that, you can delete the library if it is useless or change the version of it. Otherwise, let this issue to the author.

Comment: It is also possible to overwrite the manifest values. This way you can add an `exported` value for the entries in the dependencies.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I don't get it. Can you edit my answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925501/android-how-can-i-override-exported-tag-in-manifest/69925703#69925703

Comment: I see. It can be overwritten. I don't need to delete.