# AndroidManifest error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-api-31

When I changed the target and compile SDK version from 30 to 31 I get an error. Something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70169206/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity), but it has no answers.

> Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

But all activities with intent-filter already have `andoird:exported` attribute.
My android-manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bsuir.testapp.presentation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

    <application
        android:name="com.bsuir.testapp.presentation.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".screens.launchscreen.SplashScreen"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.history.view.HistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/history_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.availabledevices.view.AvailableDevicesActivity"
            android:label="@string/devices_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.settings.view.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".screens.dashboard.view.DashboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What could be causing the error?

Comment: what's your androidx.test:core  library version?

Comment: I do not have a given library. It is mandatory for API 31?

Comment: no it's not mandatory

Comment: even if I delete all the `activity` except for the splashScreens with `andoid: exported = "true"` - I get an error

Comment: try it and let me know it works or not

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554294/androidexported-needs-to-be-explicitly-specified-for-activity-apps-targeting

Comment: yes, it helped me

Comment: happy to hear that works

Answer (score 2):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.bsuir.testapp.presentation">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />

<application
    android:name="com.bsuir.testapp.presentation.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination"
    android:supportsRtl="true">

    <activity
        android:name=".screens.launchscreen.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".screens.history.view.HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/history_name"android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".screens.availabledevices.view.AvailableDevicesActivity"
        android:label="@string/devices_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".screens.settings.view.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/settings_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ComposePagination.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".screens.dashboard.view.DashboardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

Update  android:exported="true" only for Launcher activity and remaining Activities  android:exported="false"

Answer (score 0):

change exported to true Splashscreen Activity
like below

```
 <activity
        android:name=".screens.launchscreen.SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `android:exported="true"` for launcher activity and `android:exported="false"` for all other's activity

like below

```
<activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: i did it but it didn't help